# Числовой Enum в JAVA

Tags: java, enum

Уже есть готовый проект с абониментами. В зависимости от абонимента в нем варьируется кол-во посещаемых дней.
Есть на 10, 20, 30, 50 посещений. В базе данных и в классе это всё уже хранится как int.
Столкнулся с проблемой когда захотел заменить в классе значение поля кол-во дней вместо int на enum т.к. не могу создать его

```
public enum Days {
    10, 20, 30, 50
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему

Comment: Можеть быть, вам массив нужен или  Set?

Comment: добавьте нижнее подчеркивание

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен именно `enum`, то можно например так:

```
public enum Days {
    DAYS_10(10),
    DAYS_20(20),
    DAYS_30(30),
    DAYS_50(50);

    public final int count;

    Days(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

И получить значение можно так:

```
Days.DAYS_30.count
```

**UPD**

> как мне тоскать значения из бд когда там уже 10, 20, 30 лежит в таблице?

Ну например так:

```
Days days;
if (count == 10) days = Days.DAYS_10;
else if (count == 20) days = Days.DAYS_20;
else if (count == 30) days = Days.DAYS_30;
else days = Days.DAYS_50;
```

Comment: как мне тоскать значения из бд когда там уже 10, 20, 30 лежит в таблице?

Comment: @Данил можно как в обновленном ответе или добавить метод в enum:
        public static Optional<Days> find(int count) {
            Days[] values = values();
            for (Days value : values) {
                if (value.count == count)
                    return Optional.of(value);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }

И затем использовать так:
        int count = 30;
        Optional<Days> days = Days.find(count);